# partial dependence plot for quantile regression forest

Tags: r, random-forest, quantile-regression

I am using this code:

```
library(datasets)
library(quantregForest)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(randomForest)

Xtrain <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Length
        , Petal.Length
    )

Ytrain <- iris$Petal.Width

model <- quantregForest(
    x = Xtrain
    , y = Ytrain
)

plot.partial = function() {
    partialPlot(model, Xtrain, x.var = "Sepal.Length")
    partialPlot(model, Xtrain, x.var = "Petal.Length")
}

class(model) <- "randomForest"
plot.partial()
```

What does the partial dependence plot actually show? Is this the mean prediction (rather than for example the median)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: What do I see in partial dependence plots of gbm and RandomForest?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92150/r-what-do-i-see-in-partial-dependence-plots-of-gbm-and-randomforest)

Comment: I was aware of this but I would not agree with your statement. My question was more related to the fact the model returns quantiles . .